# How to approach refactoring this code (C#, Types)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, types, game-engine

First off, my apologies for the title of question. I'm not really sure what it's called that I'm trying to accomplish so I'll just get straight to it.

I'm currently developing a game engine in c# using GDI+ and have implemented a components class. The idea is that any game object can have multiple components attached to it (Much like Unity3D has) and I want to be able to find any component of any type, by searching for what class it is.

On that note, I would like to change this piece of code:

```
Rigidbody r = obj.GetComponentOfType(typeof(Rigidbody)) as Rigidbody;
```

To look like this instead:

```
Rigidbody r = obj.GetComponentOfType<Rigidbody>();
```

How do I go about doing this?

Sorry if my question seems vague any light shed on this topic would be wonderful!

Comment: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/55331/differences-generic-getcomponentscript-vs-getcompo.html

Answer (score 6):

This is called a generic method. You can create an overload that calls your existing type-based implementation like this:

```
public T GetComponentOfType<T>()
{
    return (T) GetComponentOfType(typeof(T));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have a `List<Component>` field in your obj's type. You can use `Linq` :

```
// assuming
public class GameObject
{
    List<Component> m_Components; // all components attached to this GameObject
    public TComponent GetComponentOfType<TComponent>()
        where TComponent : Component
    {
        // Select only the ones of type TComponent and return first one
        return m_Components.OfType<TComponent>().FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

To use this : `obj.GetComponentOfType<Rigidbody>();`

Answer (score 1):

If you can't change the class, you can use an extension method:

```
public static T GetComponentOfType<T>(this [objType] obj)
where T : class
{
    return obj.GetComponentOfType(typeof(T)) as T;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to implement a generic Method like the following:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

/// <summary>
/// Base-Class
/// </summary>
public abstract class Thing
{
    private ICollection<Thing> _things;

    public Thing()
    {
        _things = new List<Thing>();
    }

    public void AddSomething(Thing toAdd)
    {
        _things.Add(toAdd);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Assuming that every type can only appear once
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="t"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public T GetComonentOfType<T>() where T : Thing
    {
        return this.GetComonentOfType(typeof(T)) as T;
    }

    public Thing GetComonentOfType(Type t)
    {
        return _things.Where(x => x.GetType() == t).Single();
    }

}

/// <summary>
/// One possible implementation
/// </summary>
public class SpecialThing : Thing
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an extension method to the GetComponentOfType method which does the dirty work for you (the first line of code you posted) and have it accept a generic type. You can then pass in the Rigidbody type in <> tags.

For more info on extension methods go [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.aspx).

Edit: Make sure your extension method is static.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is done by using generics.  The body of the GetComponentofType method would be almost identical, the only difference is that you are specifiying the type you want via a generic rather than passing it in as a parameter.

The method might look like:

```
 public T GetComponentOfType<T>(){

      //code goes here to locate the object.
      you can get the type via typeof(T) 

      return theObject;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
   public class Rigidbody{
        public int Size{ get; set; }
        public string fourgroundColor{ get; set; }
        public string backgroundColor{ get; set; }
        public int fingerammount{ get; set; }
        public int arms{ get; set; }
    }
```

create a class called Rigidbody. Set all the components to the class, than you could use it. Olso make it public, otherwise you can't use it like your example.

when you have the class you can say: var r = obj.GetComponentOfType();
olso use var instead of the datatype. var is better  the datatype is oldscool ( more like c#1 or C2.0) i made the same misstake everytime. but when i start working as sofware developer they told me to use var (i'm still just a junior, olmost medior)

Comment: IMO this answer makes no sense at all. OP asked about how to create a generic method to extract his component and you're writing about compile time type resolved method.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all component classes inherit this class (or alike):

```
public abstract class IComponent
{
    protected IList<object> objComponents;

    public object GetComponentOfType(Type type)
    {
        if (objComponents == null)
            return null;

        return objComponents.Where(obj => obj.GetType() == type).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

You can just create another main mother class to get inherited from:

```
public abstract class BaseComponent : IComponent
{
    public object GetComponentOfType<T>()
    {
        return GetComponentOfType(typeof(T));
    }
}
```

Or if you have access to the first class, just add the previous function to it.